# Error in Jenkins using SQL Server Driver

Tags: sql-server, groovy, jenkins

I'm trying to run a Groovy script to connect to Microsoft SQL Server within Jenkins and insert new data . I want to use the SQL Server driver and I placed the driver in Jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib. I get an error when I Tried to run the following code in the build step - Execute Groovy Script:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
class Connection {
    def sqlConnection

    def route = "xxxx"
    def user = "xxxx"
    def password = "xxxxx"
    def driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

    Connection(db){
        this.route+=db.toString()
        this.sqlConnection = Sql.newInstance( route, user, password, driver )
    }

    static main(args) {
        Connection con = new Connection("nameDataBase")
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
1 error org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
E:\Jenkins\workspace\pruebaDB\hudson1035758401251924782.groovy: 2:
   unable to resolve class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver @ line 2, column 1.
     import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`
```

Answer (score 0):

The most evident case of such exception is that necessary class not yet in classpath during script execution. 
During a which build step script is executed?

If my assumptions are right and you can't shift script execution time to the other build step (when all necessary classes/libs will be in the cp) try to use class loader. 
Here is a few links which should help you with this:

- [class lodding fun](http://groovy.dzone.com/news/class-loading-fun-groovy)
- [class loading in groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Class+Loading)